# Aws EC2 port 80 connection refused

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run a node js server on aws EC2

My dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Inside my `server.js` is an express web server listening for port 80.

I included port 80 into my inbound rules:
[image: security rules]

But still when I try to open a public DNS or an associated domain I get this:
[image: connection refused image]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you run your docker, have you mapped the ports from the container to the host port?

Comment: @Marcin I thought that `EXPOSE 80` is doing it, am I wrong?

Comment: "The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port." from [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose).

Comment: by the way, any luck with the ssh issue?

Comment: @Marcin Nope, still connecting with full command, idk what's wrong, I even configured an elastic ip

Comment: @Marcin also can you post your comment as an answer? So I can approve it

Comment: Answer added. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your container's **port 80 is not assigned to the host**'s port. `EXPOSE` instruction does not do this for you. From the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose):

> The EXPOSE instruction **does not actually publish the port**. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. **To actually publish** the port when running the container, **use the -p flag** on docker run to publish and map one or more ports, **or the -P flag** to publish all exposed ports and map them to high-order ports.